# Not able to access List of dict In django template

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary

I have a list in my view like

```
getit = [{u'company': u'',
  u'customerId': u'qwert',
  u'dateCreated': u'2012-10-28 08:52:43.0',
  u'dateModified': u'2012-12-17 22:27:58.0',
  u'email1': u'',
  u'email2': u'',
  u'extensionId': u'306',
  u'message': u'',
  u'name': u'',
  u'phone1': u'0284533',
  u'phone2': u'',
  u'productCode': u'12400',
  u'prospectId': u'795',
  u'status': u'0',
  u'subscriberEmail': u'naveen@hi.com',
  u'subscriberId': u'ro@gmail.com',
  u'title': u'',
  u'trackId': u'12345',
  u'vendorEmail': u'va@tal.com',
  u'vendorNumber': u'0284533'}]

context['hi'] = getit
```

I am trying to iterate these data in my template like .

```
{% for x in hi %}
   {{x.status}}
   {{x.productCode}}
{% endfor %}
```

Unfortunately not able to access in my template

Please help me out what might I amm doing wrong here

**Updated **

Here is My view

```
def  subscriberreport(request):
    context = {}

    subscriberId = request.session['subscriberId']
    REST_URL = 'http://10.10.10.76:8100/UCSRestService/prospectrequest/' + subscriberId + '/subscriber'
    context = {}
    geta = Agent()
    getr = geta.GETT('caason',REST_URL,'apikey','SecretString')
    geti = geta.response.text
    getwj = json.loads(geti)
    for i,j in getwj.items():
        if i == "data":
           getit = j
    print getit
    print type(getit)
    context['hi'] = getit

    RESTC_URL = 'http://10.10.10.76:8100/UCSRestService/calldetailrecord/' + subscriberId + '/subscriber'
    context = {}
    getac = Agent()
    getrc = getac.GETT('caason',RESTC_URL,'apikey','SecretString')
    getic = getac.response.text
    getwjc = json.loads(getic)
    print "++++++++++++++++++++++CDR+"

    for k,v in getwjc.items():
        if k == "data":
           context['cdr'] = v
        if k == "error":
           context['cdr'] = False
    context['report'] = True
    return render_to_response('actual/reports.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Looks okay to me. Are you sure you've passed the `context` object to the template render function correctly?

Comment: yes I am passing the context object      return render_to_response('actual/reports.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

Comment: What's the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: Please provide the error message. What's the behaviour you get ? Your code should be working, IMO. Try to use something like django-debug-toolbar to verify your context, and try to print `hi` to see how it's rendered, using `{{ print hi }}`

Comment: I am not getting any error message

Comment: So try to print each element of the list `{% for x in hi %}{{ x }}{% endfor %}`. You can also add an `{% empty %}` clause to check that your list is not empty.

Comment: What are you getting? What do you expect? There's only one item in `getit`, you should be getting `0 12400`.

Comment: Also skip the list if you're not going to have more than 1 value in it. Its redundat and only clutters your template.

Comment: You're clearing your context `context = {}` after insterting getit inside of it. Also, this code is AWFULLY HORRIBLE. This means that your template context does not contain this 'hi' element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the line with :

```
context = {}
```

And you'll be okay. (This line clears the context dict, so your data is erased)

Sidenote, your code is awful, I recommend cleaning that up.

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhh    a lot can happen with a small   mistake

Comment: A lot can happen with such coding quality :) Try to improve your code semantics and structure, and this should not happen. Also note, your mistakes looks like it is coming from copy/pasting code parts. Copy/pasting code parts is always a bad thing.

Answer (score 2):

You are resetting the context to empty after you add `getit` to it:

```
context['hi'] = getit

...

context = {}    # here's your problem
```